# how to create day/night mode for my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, tintcolor

I am looking to create a toggle in my application

`Day  |  Night`

Day is considered the default setting. When the user selects the `Night` mode i want all the color of all the UI elements to be **`inverted`**.

Here are the kind of elements i mean:

1. UILabels
2. Buttons
3. Tabs
4. Pickers
5. Window Backgrounds
6. Everything else that is a UI object

I have tried using the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

**This has the following issues:**

1. This does change the color of many elements of the app but not
   all. Like for instance it does not change the color of the UILabels
2. It does not invert the color. It simply changes the color for all
   the object to a particular value.
3. Does not change the background color of the window.

Is this even possible with a quick bit of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use the `UIAppearance` for customize your labels, buttons, etc.
You can see [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/108766/uiappearance-tutorial) tutorial. I think this can help you.